# How to Assign gridview column value to item template Textbox?

Tags: gridview

here I have a trouble to get value from bound field to template field..

Here when user click edit link in gridview, the boundfield value should transfer to textbox control inside of the item template.

how to solve this?

Comment: why don't you assign `MyTextBox` the same value of the `Boundfield`?

Comment: Actually, I have to get boundfield value and assign it in to TextBox, which is present in itemTemplate.how to do that?